# Is splitting of an ag-Grid across multiple DIVs possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ag-grid, vuejs2

Working on a web-app project that uses ag-Grid for tabular data within a Vue2.js component, with 2 or 3 fields and a subsection accessible through a tree-format descending below each record.

Since the grid is so narrow, I'd like to have it span across several DIVs. The app is meant to be view-able on either desktops, tablets, or mobile phones, so responsive design of the tabular data is important (single column on mobiles, multiple columns (DIVs) on a desktop, for example).

Has anyone had experience with this?  Googling keeps throwing me back to the ag-Grid documentation on grouping an aggregation, but that does not really address what I am looking for.

Supporting image:
[image: visual idea of what I'd like to accomplish...blue column just represents the start of the grid, and it's content wraps to the other columns]
*Visual idea of what I'd like to accomplish...blue column just represents the start of the grid, and it's content wraps to the other columns.*

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. "Since the grid is so narrow, I'd like to have it span across several DIVs" - if you are saying here that the ag-grid is narrow... why would you want it to span several DIVs?

Comment: so that the column of data is spread across several columns (like in the supporting image) to be able to read more data at one time on larger screens, yet still be responsive to display on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that modifying ag-Grid's table output structure (built conveniently with DIVs) using CSS3's Multi-column Layout support via `display: inline-block` and `column-count` is the direction of solution I am looking for.

By applying them to the style for the DIV that emulates the outer `<table>` rule/structure, it appears to 'auto split' the data rows within into the number of columns I decide.  Next is to attempt to modify that using media queries based on screen width.

Fiddle example for using `column-count`: https://jsfiddle.net/digitalmouse/9casq77v/

So unless anyone else can provide something even better, this looks like the way to go.